# Cómo modifico un objeto desde otro archivo de typescript en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy tratando de reducir código en mi aplicación, por lo que tengo la necesidad de crear un servicio aparte que se encargue de modificar esos objetos enviados por referencia.

En la siguiente imagen pueden observar que lo comentado es código repetido, por esa razón cree un método en un servicio para que se encargue de ejecutar ese procedimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esa otra imagen está mi servicio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no uso el servicio y descomento todo, todo trabaja como quiero, es decir, se modifican todos los objetos. Sin embargo, si trato de usar el servicio, los unicos objetos que no cambia es el de "Employee" mejor dicho el método **filter** no trabaja. Tanto el **push** como el **splice** si funciona.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que pasa? :c

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, hice que el método de mi servicio retorne el arreglo que no hacía cambios y lo volví a definir en mi array de objetos de mi archivo TS.